# cordova-plugin-googlemaps how to trigger the info_window of marker from marker array

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having hard time in showing info window of particular marker selected from marker array.

I'm using this plugin https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Map with cordova.

I can move the Camera to particular marker location as I have latLng of the marker from the array but how to trigger the Info_window of the same Marker. Please Help

Comment: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/marker

Comment: Yes I'm looking for more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution for this.
While adding marker on map. the function returns marker object, push the object an array. for an idea,

```
for(var i= 0; i < data.length; i++){
   map.addMarker({
       'position': data[i].latLng,
       'title' : i
             }, function(marker){
              arrayOfMarkers.push(marker);
                 })
```

to invoke info_window

```
arrayOfMarker[i].show_infoWindow();
```

*don't go on the syntax, grab the idea